# How can I set an element id to active when another component is scrolled into view?

Tags: reactjs

So I have a sidebar and inside of it multiple buttons. When I click on the particular button, it scrolls into view a component with a certain name(I have one page with multiple components). And it works fine, components scroll into view,

but I want to set a list item id to active, according to the current component in view, so it changes color, but in the other li items active class is removed.

- SideBar.jsx:

```
const Sidebar = () => {
  const [sideBar, setSidebar] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="sidebar">
      <span class="btn" onClick={() => setSidebar(!sideBar)}>
        Menu
      </span>
      <div className="profile">
        <img src={spike} />
        <span>Alim Budaev</span>
        <span>Available for work</span>
      </div>
      <ul className="sidebarlist" id={sideBar ? "hidden" : ""}>
        {SlidebarData.map((val, key) => {
          return (
            <li
              className="row"
              id={val.link == val.title ? "active" : ""}
              key={key}
              onClick={() => {
                document.getElementById(val.link).scrollIntoView();
              }}
            >
              <div>{val.title}</div>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

So as you can see, I have a ul with list items, and when I click on each one, it scrolls a certain div into view. I also SidebarData.js file, where I store all data as an array:

- SidebarData.js

```
export const SlidebarData = [
  {
    title: "Home",
    link: "home"
  },
  {
    title: "About",
    link: "about"
  },
  {
    title: "Services",
    link: "services"
  },
  {
    title: "Contact",
    link: "contact"
  }
];
```

So when a particular div is in view, I want to set a li id to active, but I can't figure out how I can tell li to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're changing `id` instead of class on `li` and `id` can’t be duplicate, it is not assigned correctly.
Instead of using id in your code, you might use `ref`.
here is a sample code to add `active` class to `li` based on elements in view.

```
const Sidebar = () => {
  const [sideBar, setSidebar] = useState(false);
  const [selectedLink, setSelectedLink] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="sidebar">
      <span className="btn" onClick={() => setSidebar(!sideBar)}>
        Menu
      </span>
      <div className="profile">
        <img src={spike} />
        <span>Alim Budaev</span>
        <span>Available for work</span>
      </div>
      <ul className="sidebarlist" id={sideBar ? "hidden" : ""}>
        {SlidebarData.map((val, key) => {
          return (
            <li
              className={`row ${selectedLink === val.link ? "active" : ""}`}
              id={val.link}
              key={key}
              onClick={() => {
                setSelectedLink(val.link);
                document.getElementById(val.link).scrollIntoView();
              }}
            >
              <div>{val.title}</div>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: hello! your code worked, the active item changes color, but now it doesn't scroll other divs into view, does it have something to do with setState?

Comment: I don’t think so, diff the changes and try to remove new change one by one you'll find out the reason

Comment: hey @Carl try now I have updated code, I think it might be due to a different image source

Comment: oh no, i copied just the code that you've changed, so i guess it's not the problem with img, but anyway, i'll try to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your solution. One is that your SlidebarData has different titles and links. Thus, when using val.link === val.title in Sidebar hook, you're getting `false` on the condition, returning the id as **blank.**

On the other hand, I'm not sure how you're not getting an error with `document.getElementById(val.link).scrollIntoView();`. The value of val.link is going to be either Home, About, ...; however, you're setting the id of each *li* as either "active" or blank (""). So, `document.getElementById(val.link)` should return `null` and not the element.

---

**EDIT:** Does this solve your problem?

If you want to set the id which is active when pressed, do not use the keyword *active* as you'll have to change all the other id's. Create a state variable `currentId` (for example), and use it to set the current item you've selected.

```
const Sidebar = () => {
  const [sideBar, setSidebar] = useState(false);
  const [currentId, setCurrentId] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="sidebar">
      <span class="btn" onClick={() => setSidebar(!sideBar)}>
        Menu
      </span>
      <div className="profile">
        <span>Alim Budaev</span>
        <span>Available for work</span>
      </div>
      <ul className="sidebarlist" id={sideBar ? "hidden" : ""}>
        {SlidebarData.map((val, key) => {
          return (
            <li
              className="row"
              id={val.link}
              key={key}
              onClick={() => {
                setCurrentId(val.link);
                document.getElementById(val.link).scrollIntoView();
              }}
            >
              <div>{val.title}</div>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>

      <div>{currentId}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Edit #2**: Here is the codesandbox link, so you can have a look at the behaviour of the aforestated code.

https://codesandbox.io/s/fluent-ui-example-forked-rbd9p?file=/index.js

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API), which will allow you to monitor and react to events which occur when tracked elements intersect a parent element (or the viewport).

Implementing this in React is non-trivial and will likely involve [forwarding refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) for each tracked element, however, you might find one or more community modules which already exist (e.g. [`react-intersection-observer`](https://github.com/thebuilder/react-intersection-observer)).